# hashchange, pushState with jQuery BBQ -- Adding characters to URL

Tags: jquery, hashchange, pushstate

I have a Fiddle to look at. The hashchange will not work in jsFiddle, but you can at least see the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/LpgFt/

When I click on links the URL changes to:

```
index.html#url=%23about-us
```

rather than:

```
index.html#about-us
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your code to  `$.bbq.pushState({ href });`

Check out this [fiddle (not in iframe)](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbb6y/show/) ... and the actual [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/rbb6y/)

Updated code

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr( "href" );
  $.bbq.pushState({ href });
  return false;
});

 $(window).bind( "hashchange", function(e) {
    var url = e.getState( "url" );
    $("a").each(function(){
      var href = $(this).attr( "href" );
    });
  });

  $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
```

Comment: `$.bbq.pushState({ href });` Either the key/value of `{href}` is missing... Is that valid javascript?